# Capturing data using $ _GET in foreach ($ data as $ key => $ value) {

Tags: php

In `id==2` I am not able to capture the data (`url` and `title`) of the `array` of `id==1` using `$ _GET`. Where am I going wrong?

P.S.: I do not intend to use an external library.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
//var_dump($_GET);

if ($id == 1) {
    $re = '/href="(?P<link>.*?)" title="(?P<title>.*?)" class="iGh__menu-link/';
    $html = file_get_contents('https://www.ig.com.br/');

    preg_match_all($re, $html, $data);
    //print_r ($data['link']);
    //print_r ($data['title']); 
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/loja.php" . '&url=' . $data['link'][$key] . '&title=' . $data['title'][$key] . '&s=1&logo=""';
    }
} else if ($id == 2) {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $title = $_GET['title'];
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the data in the loop, you don't `echo` it or store it as a variable, is that on purpose?

Comment: You use the foreach loop wrong. I suggest you read its [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to understand it better. `$key` can be only "link" or "title" in the code you posted.

Comment: @klenium.  Am sorry. I am still learning php. Could you help me mount the loop correctly?

Comment: @grumpycrouton. Am sorry. I am still learning php. Could you help me mount the loop correctly?

Comment: @AntonioOliveira It appear that you need a bit of support on this question as well.  Can you explain where you are stuck after receiving some feedback?  Please explain your task and what the expected result is.  More specifically, what do you intend to do in the foreach loop?

Comment: @mickmackusa, the question is specifically linked to the header of the web page. I was successful using the function below. I tried to do the same using file_get_contents, but I caught the part that does not use the cookie on the main page ID1 (if ($ curlheader == "None") and yes in ID2 if ($ curlheader == "main"). Could it help me to create this same function using file_get_contents and not cURL?

Comment: `if ($curlheader == "None") { curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);}
    if ($curlheader == "main") {curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$cookie_file = "mMcookie.txt";
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);`

Comment: If you have a working solution, please post your code on this page and explain how it works, then award your answer the green tick so that the system removes question from the "unanswered" list and future volunteers will know you have a solution.  If you would like your working code to be reviewed, the best course of action is to post a new question on CodeReview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `$_GET` for below if its empty than store none

```
$id=isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:"";
```

if `$_GET` get empty than store none otherwise store value on `id` and also check witch `method` you use to send data like `post,get` etc..,

Comment: Am sorry. I am still learning php. Could you help me mount the loop correctly?

Comment: where is data come in `$data` variable without any assignment